# Center of mass of a right circular cone

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How can one find the center of a right circular cone with height $h$ and radius $r$?

I've found these formulas:

$$M_{xy} = \iiint\limits_V z \rho (x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$$

$$M_{yz} = \iiint\limits_V x \rho (x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$$

$$M_{zx} = \iiint\limits_V y \rho (x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$$

$$M = \iiint\limits_V \rho (x,y,z) \, dx \, dy \, dz$$

We can assume that $\rho (x,y,z)=1$

A right circular cone with vertex pointing up, with height $h$ and base radius $r$ with base located at $z=0$ can be parameterized by:

$$x = \frac{h-u}{h} r \cos \varphi$$

$$y = \frac{h-u}{h} r \sin \varphi$$

$$z=u$$

$$u \in [0,h], \ \ \varphi \in [0, 2 \pi)$$

My problem is that I've calculated these integrals:

$$M_{xy} = \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \int_0 ^h u\,du\,d \varphi = \pi h^2$$

$$M_{yz} = \int_0 ^{2 \pi} \int_0^h \frac{h-u}{h}r \cos \varphi\, du \,d \varphi = 0$$ and similarly $M_{zx} = 0$.

$$M = \int \int \, du  \, d \varphi = \int_0^{2 \pi}h \, d \varphi = 2h \pi.$$

There must be a mistake somewhere, because the center of mass of a right circular cone is at $\frac{3}{4}$ of its height.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: $\frac14$ of its height, I think.

Comment: That depends if we measure from the vertex or from the base. Either way the result isn't correct in my case ;)

Comment: @Hagrid : You use both $H$ and $h$.  Are those supposed to be both the same thing?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Yes, they are. I'll correct it right now.

Comment: Your first warning sign should be that you started with triple integrals and somehow they transformed into double integrals with your parameterization. In fact this parameterization is only the slanted face of the cone, not the entire volume.

Comment: Ok, so what did I miss?

Comment: @Hagrid : If you want to use polar coordinates, you're going to need a triple integral with $\displaystyle\int\cdots\cdots\,dr$ in there somewhere. But this whole thing makes the matter more complicated that it really is, I think.

Comment: For instance, the volume of a cone (and therefore $M$) is $\frac13 \pi r^r h$, not $2h\pi$.

Comment: Could you write the correct formula for the parametrization of the cone and tell me what is missing in those integrals, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the circular symmetry, it is obvious that the center of mass is on the $z$ axis. The $z$ component of the center of mass is
$$
\frac{\int_V z \rho \;\mathrm{d}v}{\int_V \rho \;\mathrm{d}v} = \frac{M_{xy}}{M}
$$
But you mis-calculated both $M$ and $M_{xy}$.

By far the easiest way to do these integrals is to work in cylindrical coordinates $(s, \phi, z)$ where the usual notation is to call the radial coordinate $r$ or $\rho$ but since the statement of the problem uses those two letters I use $s$ instead of $r$.  The integrals are easy but one must remember that the volume element is $s\;\mathrm{d}s\;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z$ rather than just $\mathrm{d}s\;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z$. Take $\rho = 1$ as before:

\begin{align}
M &= \int_{z=0}^{h} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{s=0}^{r \frac{h-z}{h} } s\;\mathrm{d}s\;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z
=\int_{z=0}^{h} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \frac{r^2}{2} \left(\frac{h-z}{h}\right)^2\;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z \\[8pt]
&= \int_{z=0}^{h} \pi r^2\left(\frac{h-z}{h}\right)^2\;\mathrm{d}z 
= \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} \int_{0}^{h} (z-h)^2\;\mathrm{d}z = \frac{\pi r^2}{3h^2} \left[ (z-h)^3 \right]_{0}^{h} \\
M &=  \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
M_{xy} &= \int_{z=0}^{h} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \int_{s=0}^{r \frac{h-z}{h} } z s\;\mathrm{d}s\;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z
=\int_{z=0}^{h} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} z \frac{r^2}{2} \left(\frac{h-z}{h}\right)^2 \;\mathrm{d}\phi\;\mathrm{d}z \\[8pt]
&= \int_{z=0}^{h} \pi z r^2\left(\frac{h-z}{h}\right)^2 \;\mathrm{d}z 
= \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} \int_{0}^{h} z(z-h)^2 \;\mathrm{d}z 
= \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} \int_{0}^{h} \left( z^3 - 2 z^2 + z \right) \;\mathrm{d}z \\[8pt]
&= \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} \left[ \frac{z^4}{4} -\frac{2 z^3}{3} + \frac{z}2 \right]_{0}^{h} \\[8pt]
&=  \frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}
= \frac{\pi r^2}{h^2} h^4 \left( \frac{1}{4} - \frac{2}{3} +\frac{1}{2} \right) \\[8pt]
M_{xy} &= \frac{\pi r^2 h^2}{12}
\end{align}

$$
z_{CM} = \frac{M_{xy}}{M} = \frac{h}{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you very, very much. As a matter of fact, I've just started reading about cylindrical coordinates and Jacobians, so now I even understand why there is $s ds d\phi dz$. Could you tell me why $s$ goes from $0$ to $r \frac{h-z}{h}$?

Comment: @MarkFischler : You wrote things like s ds d\phi dz, with spaces between s and ds, between ds and d\phi, etc., as if you intended those spaces to be visible in the rendered notation.  But they're not.  That's how TeX and LaTeX and MathJax work.  I changed your code to s\,ds\,d\phi\,dz.  Also, you used "array" where "align" is somewhat more appropriate, and I changed that.

Comment: For Hagrid's question: If you are at height $z$ then what would your radius be at that height?  When $z=0$ you are at zero radius; when z=h you are at the base radius $r$. And $s(z)$ is linear.

Comment: For Michael's point: Thank you.  I mis-remembered how to add thin space in LaTeX and couldn't find my LaTeX book. I was trying to use \/ instead of \, and of course that didn't work so I gave up. By the way, you also got the italicized $d$ to become non-italic; is that an effect of the Ajax TeX processing, because LaTeX does not do that for \,.

Answer (score 5):

I'd look at cross-sections parallel to the base.  The radius of the cross-section at height $z$ from the base is $r(h-z)/h$, so the area is $\pi r^2(h-z)^2/h^2$.  So the infinitesimal element of volume at that height is $\pi r^2(h-z)^2\,dz/h^2$.  Integrating $z$ with respect to volume, for the $z$-coordinate of the center of gravity, we get
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\iiint z\,dV}{\displaystyle\iint 1\,dV} = \frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{h^2} \int_0^h z\Big(\pi r^2(h-z)^2\,dz\Big)}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{h^2}\int_0^h \pi r^2(h-z)^2\,dz}.
$$

The factor $\pi r^2$ does not depend on $z$, so it cancels from the numerator and the denominator.  So you have
$$
\frac{\int_0^h z(h-z)^2\,dz}{\int_0^z(h-z)^2\,dz} = \frac{\int_h^0 (h-w)w^2\,(-dw)}{\int_h^0 w^2(-dw)} = \frac{h^4/3 -h^4/4}{h^3/3} = \frac h 4.
$$

If you have a pyramid with a non-circular base, the area at height $z$ is still $(\text{constant}\cdot(h-z)^2)$, and the "constant" depends on the shape, but the "constant" again appears as a factor in both the numerator and the denominator and cancels.

Answer (score 4):

The distance from the top of the cone to the center of mass is given by:

$$\frac{3}{h^{3}}\int_{0}^{h}x^{3}dx$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{x_{1} \equiv x\,,\quad x_{2} \equiv y\,\quad x_{3} \equiv z}$.

> $\large\tt\mbox{With the vertex at the origin:}$
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large x_{{\rm i\ cm}}}\,\pars{{1 \over 3}\,\pi r^{2}h}
> &\equiv\int_{V}x_{i}\,\dd V
> =\int_{V}\nabla\cdot\pars{{1 \over 4}\,x_{i}\vec{R}}\,\dd V
> =\int_{S}{1 \over 4}\,x_{i}\,\vec{R}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
> \\[3mm]&=\left.{1 \over 4}
> \int_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ <\ r^{2}}\ x_{i}h\,\dd x\,\dd y
> \,\right\vert_{z\ =\ h}
> \end{align}

By symmetry considerations, it's obvious that $\ds{x_{\rm cm} = y_{\rm cm} = 0}$.

> \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large z_{\ cm}}\,\pars{{1 \over 3}\,\pi r^{2}h}&
> ={1 \over 4}\,h^{2}\
> \overbrace{\left.\int_{x^{2}\ +\ y^{2}\ <\ r^{2}}\dd x\,\dd y\,
> \right\vert_{z\ =\ h}}^{\ds{=\ \pi r^{2}}}
> \end{align}

$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\mbox{Vertex at the origin:}\qquad &
\color{#66f}{\large z_{\rm cm}} & = & \color{#66f}{\large{3 \over 4}\,h}
\\
\mbox{Base at}\ xy-\mbox{surface}\qquad &
\color{#66f}{\large z_{\rm cm}} & = & h - {3 \over 4}\,h
=\color{#66f}{\large {1 \over 4}\,h}
\end{array}
$$