# Centre of mass of the shape formed when a hemisphere is attached to a cone(an ice-cream cone shape)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

What is the centre of mass of a hemisphere attached to a cone?
I know that the bounds for the integration with respect to z must be the two equations( lower bound being the equation of the cone and the upper bound being the equation of the hemisphere, both with z as the subject) itself but I can't seem to be able to integrate that so I am unable to find out the centre of mass of the figure

Equation of the sphere(in this case hemisphere) $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$

Equation of cone is:$(x^2+y^2)=z^2$

The bounds for both x and y and from -3
 to 3

Assuming that the density is a constant=1

The formulas are:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The figure doesn't look like it's a _hemisphere_ attached to the cone, more like a _spherical cap_. Possibly the whole thing is intended to be a [spherical sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector).

Comment: Where is the centre of the sphere? What is the radius of the sphere?

Comment: The equations are given, and I am sorry for removing the image( I could not find a good one and nor does my grapher allow me to remove parts of the graph that I don't need, so that I can make the shape look like an ice-cream cone.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you computed the circle where the two objects intersect?

Comment: I just typed that in:)

Comment: I don't see an equation for the curve of intersection; perhaps I'm misreading. Anyhow, I'd recommend using polar coordinates for this problem, with the integral over "radius" being the innermost integral.

Comment: I understand that, but what do i take as the bounds for integration with respect to z when using spherical coordinates.

Comment: Determine the mass and the centre of mass both for a cone and a hemisphere, then apply a [weighted mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean).

Comment: Would that work here?

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495520/center-of-mass-of-semi-sphere and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820594/center-of-mass-of-a-right-circular-cone